# Error when importing a Gradle project into Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to import a Gradle project into Android Studio and get the following error:

[image: Error Bitmap]

This project does indeed compile when I run Gradle from the command line.  I can also Open the project in Android Studio (vs Import) but then it tries to build using the Eclipse build script.

The gradle build was created by hand and not via the Eclipse export function.

My problem can be resolved in one of two ways:

1) Tell me how to force Android Studio to use Gradle instead of using the Eclipse build.

2) Help me find the reason for the Gradle import error.

I am using

- Android Studio 0.2.2
- Gradle 1.6 via gradlew

Comment: Not sure, but what you could try is to use the idea plugin, and generate the project files using that, and see if that works?

Comment: which Idea plugin?  Is that to use with Gradle or Eclipse?  The thing is, the gradle setup works on the command line.  I just need to bring it into Android Studio...

Comment: That's a Gradle plugin: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html

Comment: I added the idea pluging, ran './gradlew idea' it generated some files but they don't work.  It generated a project.ipr file, which I opened but it only loaded my main module and not the other modules.  Any ideas Erik?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why this didn't work.

There are two ways to include a project from within the settings.gradle file:

> include ':..:source:compA-api'

and

> include "source:compA-api"
>
> project(':source:compA-api').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'source/compA/api')

I had used the second form and apparently Android Studio didn't like that :)